# using GET call to connect login form to a url in swing

Tags: java, swing, http, rest, get

I want to create a Login Form in Swing JAVA and when the user clicks on the submit button it should use a GET call to GET the user information from a URL.
My login form is having  two fields:
username:
password:
 and "submit" button

I have used the following code. I am working in NetBeans 7.1.2 .I new to Java.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)throws IOException
  {
 String value1=text1.getText();
String value2=text2.getText();
URL url = new URL("http://link?      userName=value1&password=value2");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
httpCon.setDoOutput(true); httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter( httpCon.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
out.close();
```

}

but it is not working .
Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong OR can give me better way to do this.

```
 * @author tapasweni
 */
class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
```

I am using this but now I am getting error code 404 whereas if I typed the URL in the browser it is giving me the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you coded the litterals "value1" and "value2" and not their variables in the URL. Try this instead:

```
URL url = new URL("http://wisekar.iitd.ernet.in/active/api_resources.php/method/user?userName="+value1+"&password="+value2);
```

Note that you should use a URLEncoder (with charset UTF-8) to encode those values.

Comment: 1) Change `catch(Exception e)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}` to `catch(Exception e)
  { e.printStackTrace(); 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}` 2) Copy/paste the exception output & `System.out` (for the URL). 3) I edited the linked code directly into the question.  Few people will follow links, and they are less helpful to future users.

Comment: Now I am getting error code 404, but when I am typing the same URL in the browser Iam getting the correct result.

Comment: @tapasweni remove the calls to `httpCon.setDoOutput(true); httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");` and also drop the OutputStreamWriter as you are not doing any output. You will then get the proper result

Comment: @Guillaume Pole Thanks :)! it worked. Can you please tell me if I want to print it's default  .json array how can I do that.

Comment: @tapasweni If the connection was successful, you can access the response content with: `httpCon.getInputStream();` and then read the content of the input stream. If the connection failed or the server returned an error (4XX and 5XX code) you should then access the error stream: `httpCon.getErrorStream()`

Comment: Okay thanks again. can you please tell me why removing those lines from my code made the code to work .Any explanation? as I am very new to this.